# uninitialized constant Ckeditor::Picture i am getting this on production environment

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sass, ckeditor, activeadmin

prod environment is througing  error as :

```
message :   uninitialized constant Ckeditor::Picture
file. :     /bundler/gems/ckeditor-a4232ec9a5e3/lib/ckeditor.rb:146


 parameters
 {
  "CKEditor": "search_content_description",
  "CKEditorFuncNum": "123",
  "action": "index",
  "controller": "ckeditor/pictures",
  "langCode": "en-gb"
 }

  environment
 {
  
"program_name": "bin/rails"

 }
```

Can anyone have idea how to resolve the error or any idea how to replicate the same error on local enviorment

my ckeditor.rb file is

```
Ckeditor.setup do |config|
    # //cdn.ckeditor.com/<version.number>/<distribution>/ckeditor.js
    config.cdn_url = "//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.1/full/ckeditor.js"
  end
```

gems file contains:

```
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'slim-rails'

gem 'ruby-kafka'

# Gem for CK-editor
gem 'ckeditor', github: 'galetahub/ckeditor'
```